# What is the difference between .lbl and .zpl extension?

Tags: zebra-printers

I have a code which generates a **ZPL** file which can be sent directly to a printer or downloaded like a file with a **.zpl** extension. My question is what is the difference between this **.zpl** and **.lbl** extension files? The code for the **ZPL** is below.

```
^XA

^FX Top section with logo, name and address.
^CF0,60
^FO210,100^FDCompany Name Here^FS

^FX Second section with item information
^CFA,30
^FO30,300^FDITEM NAME: Printer^FS
^FO30,340^FDSERIAL NO: 12345^FS

^FX Third section with bar code.
^BY4,2,250
^FO100,550^BC^FDsparc123^FS

^XZ
```

If they are the same does it mean I can change the file extension from .**zpl** to **.lbl** and print it without a problem?

Comment: The printer should not see the extension. You would not send the file to the printer, but rather the contents of the file as a stream. What you have above is exactly what you would send to the printer.

Comment: You should explain where your lbl files come from and what an example content looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.lbl extension is the one produced by a label design software (.lbl is the extension of the files created by zebradesigner 2, for example, while .nlbl is the extension of zebradesigner 3), while .zpl files contain the zpl code the printer actually needs to produce a label.
You can better picture the difference comparing the .lbl (or .nlbl) files as a .docx file and a .zpl file as a .txt file
If you open a .lbl file with a text editor, you'll see it doesn't contain zpl commands, so you can't simply swap the file extensions